# Comparing articles with composite PK in ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Before I take a POST request, the application should compare the input object whether it exists in the database table. The problem for my intention is, that the db table has two primary keys and when I'm try to compare it, then it tells me the article is not exist because the first PK `Id` will automatically increased. So, important for me is the second PK `isin`.

The following code doesn't work:

```
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(Fon))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostFond(Fon fon)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     return BadRequest(ModelState);
  }

  var fonds = db.Fon.Find(fon.Id, fon.isin);
  if (fonds.isin != null)
  {
     return BadRequest(ModelState); //ISIN already exists.
  }

  db.Fon.Add(fon);
  await db.SaveChangesAsync();

  return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = fon.Id }, fon);
}
```

How can I check whether the isin is existing or new?!

---

EDIT: (SOLUTION)

I've tried many things and come to the correct solution. The following code illustrates it:

```
var fonds = db.Fon
              .Where(f => f.isin == fon.isin)
              .FirstOrDefault();

if (fonds != null)
{
    return Conflict();
}

db.Fon.Add(fon);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: instead of using `Find`, you can use `FirstOrDefault` (or another LINQ operation) and treat the property like any other column, rather than the PK

Comment: @Jonesopolis I can't use `FirstOrDefault`.. the syntax highlighting tells: `.DbSet<WebApi.Fon> does not contain definition for "FirstOrDefault"...`

Comment: add a reference to `System.Linq`

Comment: @Jonesopolis `using System.Linq` is already added but the Syntax Highlighting tells the same error.